# In the top of NavigationView has shadow,How can I remove it?

Tags: android

[image: Layout image]

I am sorry about that my English is horrible，**thanks for your help！**

This code is my **fragments layout**.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end">
    <com.wk.reservation.view.PullListView
        android:id="@id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/white">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_right_header_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```

Comment: put your complete xml file source code where you are using this navigation bar.

Comment: thank you,It is the android support bug,I use the version is 23.2.1,when I change to 23.1.1,the shadow disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same bug, when i upgrade the android libraries to the 23.2.0 that shadow appears in my projects, so the only way i found to resolve the bug is downgrade the libraries version to 23.1.1:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

Comment: This is my first time to ask question in stackoverflow,I don't know am I accepted your answer?The green tick?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's already too late to answer this but for the version

```
'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

you can try adding

```
app:insetForeground="@android:color/transparent"
```

So navigation view would look like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:insetForeground="@android:color/transparent"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
                app:menu="@menu/main_drawer">
```

Comment: Thanks Carl! I just set insetForeground to @null and it worked for my specific problem.